# How to make Vim close Syntastic buffer when closing main file?

Tags: plugin-syntastic

Is there a way to make Vim close Syntastic buffer when closing the main file?

I.e. I'd like Syntastic to run automatically on file opening, and "disappear" when I choose the main file with either <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or `:q!`.

With my default configuration Syntastic buffer remains (if there are unresolved warnings) and must be closed manually.

My `.vimrc` entries related to Syntastic:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

Comment: `let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0`

Comment: @lcd047 I have that option set to 0.

Comment: Then please open an issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).  Explain what you did, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: @lcd047 I will, but for the record: I added Syntastic to Pathogen, added the suggested config (ref. question body), opened a bash script with warnings from Shellcheck, closed it and the "check on quit" occurred (repeatable).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the current master HEAD.  Which is why it's probably a good idea to move this to a place that allows longer exchanges.

Comment: I never used `syntastic` but to deal with the quickfix window (which also stays open when you close the buffer) I have a mapping: `nnoremap ZZ :xall<cr>`.